# App.Config cannot access appSettings key/value pairs. The collection is always null

Tags: c#, app-config

I have an app.config that I am trying to get values out of and I am in a solution that is an executable. I have compared the output config.exe and everything is visible. When I try to set these values, they simply do not show up in the collection.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="a" value="b"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I have tried everything that I can think of and have never had this problem before. This is part of a larger solution where I cannot show the real values, but I have tested them in a console project that I created and they show up just fine. I am not sure why they wouldn't show up in this particular solution. Could any third party tools effect this?

I am trying to access them like this:

```
using System.Configuration;
private readonly string stringToSet;
public TheConstructor() 
{
  stringToSet = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
}
```

**UPDATE** I just figured out that for some reason, a class library is somehow hijacking my app.config. The solution that I am referencing the app.config thinks that I need my keys from .dll.config. How is this possible? The project that I am using the config is referencing it in the same project, not from a class library. How can this happen?

Comment: Your sample code does not compile, what is the definition and value of `key`.

Comment: It may not, but I just wanted to give you an idea what I am doing. Key is just the string representation of the key to get the value. The point is, AppSettings prop AllKeys is zero when there should be some.

Comment: Is your app.config file being copied to where the exe live and being renamed to `whatever.exe.config`?

Comment: Yes, I can see the .exe.config in the bin\debug folder and the contents are visible and all there.